# Passing VARBINARY to stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, sql-server-2008-r2, varbinary

I have some source data that is formatted as ASCII hexadecimal. I need to get it into a SQL database in  VARBINARY fields. I've reduced the problem to the bare minimum to illustrate what I'd like to do. I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BinaryDemo
    @BinaryData varbinary(max)
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT @BinaryData;
END
```

I know that it "works" because I can do:

```
DECLARE @tmp varbinary(max);
SET @tmp = CONVERT(varbinary, '1234567890abcdef', 2);
EXEC BinaryDemo @BinaryData=@tmp;
```

What I'd like to do is skip the intermediate steps and invoke the procedure like:

```
EXEC BinaryDemo @BinaryData=CONVERT(varbinary, '1234567890abcdef', 2);
```

Unfortunately, SQL complains about the syntax: **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.**

I know that the CONVERT is correct because I can:

```
PRINT CONVERT(varbinary, '1234567890abcdef', 2);
```

and I see exactly what I expect. The first example (declare/set/exec) is really a poor option because of the nature and quantity of the source data.

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast integer and concatenate to varchar in TSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936180/cast-integer-and-concatenate-to-varchar-in-tsql)

Comment: @Martin Smith: I didn't see that particular question (and, yes, I searched). Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

nice question.

but i thont think its possible . its like :

**works good :**

```
  DECLARE @r DATETIME
    SET @r=GETDATE()

    EXEC     [dbo].[sp_myDatePrinter] @d=@r
```

**bad :**

```
DECLARE @r DATETIME
    EXEC     [dbo].[sp_myDatePrinter] @d=GETDATE();
```