# Why do I get an error using CONVERT on one of the arguments of a stored proc call?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

For some reason, the following gives me an error:

```
DECLARE @Param1 DATETIME2(3)=...; -- Assign some date/time
DECLARE @Param2 DATETIME;
DECLARE @Param3 DATETIME;

EXEC dbo.SomeStoredProc CONVERT(DATE, @Param1), @Param2 output, @Param3 output;
```

The output is a compilation failure:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'CONVERT'.

Changing it to the following fixes the problem:

```
DECLARE @Param1 DATETIME2(3)=...; -- Assign some date/time
DECLARE @Param2 DATETIME;
DECLARE @Param3 DATETIME;
DECLARE @TempDate DATE=CONVERT(DATE,@Param1);

EXEC dbo.SomeStoredProc @TempDate, @Param2 output, @Param3 output;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast integer and concatenate to varchar in TSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936180/cast-integer-and-concatenate-to-varchar-in-tsql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stored procedure parameters can't contain expressions, they have to be constant values or `@` variables. In your example, `CONVERT()` is an expression and is therefore not allowed.

The same is true for default parameter values.

Comment: Not quite true. They accept `@@` system functions. Just not the ones that take parentheses. So you can pass `@@IDENTITY` but not `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. All a bit annoying.