# SQL Server - GETUTCDATE() 'Incorrect syntax near )'

Tags: sql, t-sql

Simple question: why does the top statement work, but the bottom one fails with

> 'Incorrect syntax near ('

Code:

```
USE [Research]
GO

DECLARE @d datetime 
SELECT @d = GETUTCDATE()

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [MyApp].[DateStamp]
        @date = @d

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

This one fails:

```
USE [Research]
GO 

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [MyApp].[DateStamp]
        @date = GETUTCDATE()

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

`DateStamp` is a proc that writes a bunch of stuff to a time dimension, like financial year, quarter etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Weird - Hello or Hi keeps getting chopped off when I post.

Comment: You can't use functions as parameters, you need to assign the result to an intermediate variable first.

Comment: Even if you put "Hello" or "Hi" on your post, it's likely to be deleted by someone else anyway - the first part of your question is the part that shows up on other pages, and it's better if it gets straight to the point.

Comment: Don't worry about the hello or hi a it's not needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast integer and concatenate to varchar in TSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936180/cast-integer-and-concatenate-to-varchar-in-tsql)

Comment: (See [Automatic Salutation Removal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989) on meta)

Comment: I just like to be polite since you're giving me your time!! Funny ol' world. The salutation should be removed by the summariser. Anyway - Martin, do you want to make this an actual answer since it is :)

Comment: @LukePuplett - it is nice to be polite - but on the other hand, people tend to include statements such as "please help", or "this is urgent" - *everyone* asking a question on this site is searching for a solution to their current problem, and so the "common elements" of their questions should be assumed/removed from the questions, so we can read the bits that actually matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does the top statement work, but the bottom one fails

Assigning values to parameters in [EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) must be a value a variable or `DEFAULT`. `GETUTCDATE()` is an expression that needs to be evaluated.