# Pass scope_identity into a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, scope-identity

There are a lot of discussions about passing a `scope_identity` from a child to parent stored procedures. I have an opposite scenario where the row is inserted at parent stored procedure and I want to pass the identity value to a child stored procedure.

However, directly passing scope_identity to child procedure generates a parse error in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
create procedure parent
as
begin
   --  insert a record
   exec child scope_identity() -- this does not work
end
```

However, using a local variable resolves the issue.

```
create procedure parent
as
begin
   --  insert a record
   set @id = scope_identity()
   exec child @id -- this works
end
```

What is the reason for the failure of directly passing `scope_identity()` as input parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast integer and concatenate to varchar in TSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936180/cast-integer-and-concatenate-to-varchar-in-tsql)

Comment: Syntactically you are allowed to pass some functions (e.g. `@@IDENTITY`). Expanding this list [is an open request on the Connect site](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/352110/t-sql-use-scalar-functions-as-stored-procedure-parameters)

Comment: @Martin - Thank you. It is the first time I learned that I cannot pass an expression as a parameter after so many years. I am a bit shocked. SQL2012 is out but don't know whether this is improved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a function result as a stored procedure parameter.  You need to do you latter method, by saving the result to a variable and then passing the variable.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer. It seems that I have to live with the temporary variable.