# SQL Server : procedure call, inline concatenation impossible?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and was wondering if there is another way of writing something like

```
EXEC dbo.myProcedure (SELECT columnName FROM TableName)
```

or

```
EXEC dbo.myProcedure @myStringVariable + 'other text'
```

so that these procedure calls **actually work**, **without** putting the whole stuff into a variable first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast integer and concatenate to varchar in TSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936180/cast-integer-and-concatenate-to-varchar-in-tsql)

Comment: No it isn't possible. The stored procedure parameter list can only include literals, variables, parameters, and `@@` system functions. [Vote for this here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/352110/t-sql-use-scalar-functions-as-stored-procedure-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Concatenation in inline execution of SP is not allowed..

Assuming that your `@myStringVariable` compromises of certain text and certain dynamic text you want to concatenate it.

Why don't compute it and assign to `@myStringVariable` before making the call to proc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "without putting the whole stuff into a variable first". However, I have a solution, even though it may go against what I *think* you mean. But here it is anyway.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = ''

SELECT
    @SQL = @SQL + 'EXEC SprocName ''' + ColumnName + ''''
FROM
    MyTable 

EXEC (@SQL)
```

I use this method all the time, when I need to execute a sproc based on specific values from a table.