# Named stored proc parameters and concatenation

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cast integer and concatenate to varchar in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936180/cast-integer-and-concatenate-to-varchar-in-tsql)

How do you call a stored procedure using named parameters that have more complex values. Here is a somewhat concocted example:

```
EXEC MyStoredProc @Param1='My name is: '+@Name
```

Or:

```
EXEC MyStoredProc @Param1=CONCAT('My name is: ',@Name)
```

I get an error trying to concatenate the literal string 'My name is: ' with the variable @Name. Parentheses do not help the matter any. Is this a limitation of T-SQL (i.e., when named parameters are used, the expression after the equal sign must be a single literal or variable)?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you pass in from the source a concatenated string to begin with?

Comment: Limitation of SQL Server. See connect item linked to in above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way

```
declare @Var1 varchar(50)
select @Var1 = 'My name is: '+@Name

EXEC MyStoredProc @Param1=@Var1
```

The same is true with functions as well

you can't do this

```
EXEC MyStoredProc @Param1=getdate()
```

you need to do

```
declare @Var1 datetime
select @Var1 = getdate()

EXEC MyStoredProc @Param1=@Var1
```

Comment: You can call *some* functions inline (the `@@` prefixed ones - so `@@identity` works but `scope_identity()` doesn't)

Comment: Correct..although I think of @@ more as system variables than functions

Comment: Updated with a scalar function call example...

Comment: you have to do the concat before calling the proc