# Dynamic backup file name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I use `SQL Server 2008 R2` and want to use `Backup Devices` for create backup of my database in each day. How can I create dynamic file name in `Backup Devices'.

In below code I Create a Backup Devices but want to have Current Date (YYYY-MM-DD) in my backup file.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addumpdevice  @devtype = N'disk', @logicalname = N'My Database Backup Location', @physicalname = N'D:\Backup\Backup YYYY-MM-DD.bak'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @fn nvarchar(200)
SET @fn=N'D:\Backup\Backup'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) +'.bak'



EXEC master.dbo.sp_addumpdevice  @devtype = N'disk', 
                @logicalname = N'My Database Backup Location',
                @physicalname = @fn
```

Comment: Can I Alter Created `Backup Device` for set new physical location.

Comment: You can drop a backup device with `sp_dropdevice` and create it one more time.

Comment: If I have deferent `Backup Device`, media contents will be lost. Can I have all backups in several day from my database that have deferent name formated by date in one `Backup Device Media Contents`.

Comment: What if they have the same logicalname? I never tried it but you can :)

Comment: thanks for this!  fyi, you can do that convert as a single command CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)

Comment: @egbutter Thank you for mention that. )

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intermediate variable, store the file-name appended with the DD-MM-YYYY. and use this intermediate variable in your EXEC statement.

Refer below link for how:
[Using the result of an expression (e.g. Function call) in a stored procedure parameter list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936180/cast-integer-and-concatenate-to-varchar-in-tsql)