# Pass built-in function to stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure (SP1), I want it to call another stored procedure(SP2).

#### Code SP2

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.addOrderStatus
    (
    @orderID INT,
    @statusID INT,
    @startTime DATETIME,
    @endTime DATETIME,
    @isActive BIT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO Order_Status
    (orderID, statusID, startTime, endTime, isActive) VALUES
    (@orderID, @statusID, @startTime, @endTime, @isActive)
END
```

#### Code SP1

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].addNewOrder
(
    @customerID int,
    @restaurantID int,
    @cost float,
    @addressID int,
    @ID INT OUTPUT
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

INSERT INTO [Order] 
([customerID], [restaurantID], [cost], [addressID]) 
VALUES (@customerID, @restaurantID, @cost, @addressID);

set @ID = @@IDENTITY

EXEC addOrderStatus @ID, @statusID = 1, @startTime =  SYSDATETIME , @endTime = NULL, @isActive = TRUE
```

#### My problem

I got this exception

```
Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.
```

How could I solve it ?

Thanks advance

#### after your answers and comments

the code is

```
DECLARE @startTime DATETIME
SET @startTime = SYSDATETIME
EXEC addOrderStatus @ID, @statusID = 1, @startTime , @endTime = NULL, @isActive = TRUE
```

now I got that I have to use this form `name , value`

Comment: You can't pass a *function* to a parameter. Either declare a variable up front and assign SYSDATETIME to that, passing the variable into the parameter, or give the parameter a default value and leave it out (but if you do this you'll need to properly identify your parameters instead of being lazy and relying on ordinal position).

Comment: Also, `@isActive` is a `BIT`, not a `BOOLEAN`. I suggest you use `1` instead of `TRUE` (especially `TRUE` without quotes).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I did as you said, please check my edit qeustion

Comment: Ok, now name all of your parameters. `@customerID = @ID, @statusID = 1, @startTime = @startTime, @endTime = NULL, @isActive = 1;`

Comment: do u mean that I have to declare them all ?

Comment: I will be back after 1 hour, sorry but I have to go, please don't go

Comment: Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` rather than `@@IDENTITY`. This is more robust in case an insert trigger is added to `Order` at some point.

Comment: The only system functions that can be used inline in a stored procedure parameter list are those prefixed with `@@` such as `@@spid`. Possible duplicate of  [Using the result of an expression in a stored procedure parameter list?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4936180/73226)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit - wrong part removed**

Declare your variables first, set content to it and then pass them over.

```
DECLARE @starttime datetime;
DECLARE @statusID int;
DECLARE @endTime datetime;
DECLARE @isActive int;

SET @startTime =  GETDATE();
SET @statusID = 1;
SET @endTime = null;
SET @isActive = 1;

EXEC addOrderStatus @ID, @statusID, @startTime , @endTime, @isActive
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
EXEC addOrderStatus @ID, @statusID = 1, @startTime =  SYSDATETIME , @endTime = NULL, @isActive = TRUE
```

Try this:

```
declare @sDate datetime;
set @sDate=getdate();
EXEC addOrderStatus @ID, @statusID = 1, @startTime =  @sDate , @endTime = NULL, @isActive = TRUE
```